Banking app locks disabled people out of their application, accessibility enforcement on Play Store
I am using a banking app in a country that have no ADA Act-equivalent and recently they used Android's API (probably using either accessibilityManager.enabledAccessibilityServiceList or accessibilityManager.isEnabled to check for Accessibility services and restrict the usage of the app and by doing so, they locked all people who uses any Accessibility services on their devices, including Read Aloud, Magnification, and so-on. They put a notification with clear language that if you want to use their app, you have to disable Accessibility services.
I have tried to reason with the developer through their channel and basically told to turn off Accessibility if I wanted to access my bank account through the app or pound sand.
Realistically, is it possible to report or lodge a complaints to Google Play Store and/or Google in the United States to step-up and straighten this issue? There is a few guidelines listed on their developer portal regarding accessibility (https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/accessibility/, https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9888379). I haven't been able to find their Terms of Services for Android API usage but I guess it's illegal in the States to use their API to violate civil rights law.
I cannot rely on my country legal system because we use American Rule for legal fees.
The bank in question is currently top-10 in my region, a few hundred billion USD in total assets, and doesn't have a local branch in the United States or Europe.

I guess it's illegal in the States to use their API to violate civil rights law - is the bank you're using in the US? If not how's that relevant? Is there any local banking regulators?

No, the bank doesn't operate in the States. My thought is that because Google (and Play Store) operates from/in the States, they still have to have certain policies to follow the United States' law and the banking app may have users in the States. Is that not the case? They also have huge overreach, like how Play Store restricts any app from promoting and conducting the sale of tobacco and cannabis. I don't know whether that's because a law has passed somewhere or out of goodwill, but the policy extends worldwide.

We did have a local banking regulators, from what I've gathered by going to their office is that (1) they never faced this issue before, (2) it may falls outside their jurisdiction. I'm told to follow the bank's guideline or close my account (which is problematic because it's my payroll account and corporation here usually have exclusive contracts to only send wage/salary through contracted bank)

App distributors are generally following the local laws. If your country doesn't require accessibility features then why would they add onerous requirements? Tobacco and cannabis are regulated everywhere and their sales are restricted or forbidden outright. That's not the same for accessibility in banking.

This example is quite extreme but a few country in Africa doesn't have regulations related to CP, do you think Google would get a jail free card if they allow an app for that purpose published in their storefronts just because it follows local laws? I'm looking for a way to help myself and my peers because we're clearly a third-rate citizens in our country. If there's a way to lodge a regulatory complaints, I'm all ears. If your country doesn't require accessibility features then why would they add onerous requirements? - PR nightmare

PR is not a question about law. Talk to a reporter

Accessibility service is a double-edged sword, thus I'd kind of doubt Google would prevent apps from checking it for security reason, because Google itself has acknowledged that malware have been abusing accessibility service to steal data. (reference: Is it safe to give accessibility permission to an app?, disclosure: I wrote an answer to that question)

This is not a legal quesiton, the law wherever you are seems clear about this.

I’m voting to close this question because it is about pressuring a company, not about the law.

@ConfusedButterfly Google (probably) has to ensure that the developer complies with local laws wherever it sells or supplies the app. So your app will very likely not be on the US Google Play Store. If it is legal in your country and complies with Google's private rules then it can be distributed in your country.

Are you in fact unable to use the app without relying on accessibility services?  Which accessibility services do you depend on?

I worked on an app that was very security critical and very strongly recommended not to use the screen reader in public (because bystanders could hear what's on your screen). But it stayed enabled, because the user might be alone or might be using headphones.

@phoog Speech-to-Text, but this is like you asking "why did you park in the handicapped spaces? What's your disabilities?"

@gnasher the app is available and used in the States by our diaspora. Yes, it should on the user to exert caution as long as the app is reasonably secure. There is no difference between having Accessibility vs sharing password/using text-to-speech publicly.

@AndrewT. They should, and as I understand, did have limitations on the usage and intent of their APIs. You shouldn't, for example, blocks the app from running if users refuses to grant ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION and the app should works with COARSE location, see https://developer.android.com/develop/sensors-and-location/location/permissions LinkAja e-Wallet have this behavior and after reporting this issue to Google, the developer releases compliant version that works with ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION. I'm looking for a similar policy or possibilities of regulatory complaints in the States.

@ConfusedButterfly the specific accommodation could be relevant.  A handicapped parking space has one or two accommodations: proximity and possibly size.  Furthermore, those authorized to use the handicapped parking space are typically registered as such with a government body, which an app user isn't.  The question doesn't say whether you're concerned about the limitation because you actually depend on it or because you're concerned about others who do.
